# Checking field is empty and then adding new row with zeros?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I created a table with three fields but there are no values in these fields. Here is the screenshot of these fields.

[image]

I want to add a new row with zeros for all these three fields. Here is my code.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(selectionname,("OBJECTID","FREQUENCY","SUM_Shape_Area")) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
   if row[0] == None:
      row[0] = 0
      cursor.updateRow(row)
   else:
      print selectionname + " is not empty"
```

Selectionname is my table, a parameter defined prior to this part of my code. First, I need to check if these three fields are empty, then adding a new row with zeros if they are empty. After several tries, I still could not add a new row to the table.

Comment: To add a new row you need to be using an InsertCursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GetCount](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) to check if table is empty and [da.InsertCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) to insert a row. I dont think you should try to set objectid, let it be set automatically. If you want your own ID then add another field for it.

```
import arcpy
table = 'C:\data.gdb\table123' #Change
fields = ['freq','sum'] #Change

if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(table).getOutput(0)) == 0:
    icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table,fields)
    icur.insertRow([0,0])
    del icur
```

Comment: this is what I want and really appreciate your help! @BERA